# Material-UI Checkbox not work with Redux store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, material-ui

> The source can be accessed in [this repo](https://github.com/FallenMapoBridge/visquit-frontend/tree/util/permute)

I used Redux store to update the checkbox's check flag, and I can see that the state is perfectly changing, but things does not get applied to React components.

I think everything is fine, but checkbox is not updated when I change the state coupled with check.

- Redux store used is located in `src/redux/modules/menu.js`, and checkbox-related action creator is `checkMenuNameList` function.
- Also, checkbox code can be found in `src/containers/MenuEditContainer.js`.

```js
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'

import * as actions from '../redux/modules/menu'

import PageWrapper from '../components/base/PageWrapper'
import MenuEditWrapper from '../components/common/templates/MenuEditWrapper'
import MenuEditContent from '../components/common/content/MenuEditContent'

const MenuEditContainer = (props) => {
  const handleInputChange = name => event => {
    props.actions.changeInput({
      key: name,
      value: event.target.value
    })
    props.actions.generateMenuList(event.target.value)
  }

  const handleMenuNameCheckbox = index => event => {
    props.actions.checkMenuNameList(index)
  }

  return (
    <>
      <PageWrapper>
        <MenuEditWrapper>
          <MenuEditContent
            menuName={props.menuName}
            menuPrice={props.menuPrice}
            menuNameList={props.menuNameList}
            handleInputChange={handleInputChange}
            handleMenuNameCheckbox={handleMenuNameCheckbox}
          />
        </MenuEditWrapper>
      </PageWrapper>
    </>
  )
}

const mapStateToProps = ({ menu }) => ({
  menuId: menu.menuId,
  menuName: menu.menuName,
  menuPrice: menu.menuPrice,
  menuNameList: menu.menuNameList,
  menuNameListChosen: menu.menuNameListChosen,
})

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  actions: bindActionCreators(actions, dispatch)
})

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(MenuEditContainer)
```

```js
import React from 'react'
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'

import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper'
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography'
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField'

import FormGroup from '@material-ui/core/FormGroup'
import FormControlLabel from '@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel'
import Checkbox from '@material-ui/core/Checkbox'

import PageTitle from '../../typography/PageTitle'
import AddButtonSet from '../../button/AddButtonSet'
import EditButtonSet from '../../button/EditButtonSet'

import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles'
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    padding: theme.spacing(3, 2)
  },
  title: {
    fontWeight: 200,
    marginBottom: '1.5rem'
  },
  textField: {
    marginLeft: theme.spacing(0.5),
    marginRight: theme.spacing(1),
    width: 200,
    display: 'block'
  },
}))

const MenuEditContent = (props) => {
  const classes = useStyles()
  const { match, location, history } = props
  return (
    <Paper className={classes.root}>
      <PageTitle>
        {
        (location.pathname === '/menu/edit/new')
        ? (`새로운 메뉴 등록`)
          // 기존 메뉴 수정시
        : (match.params.menuId)
          ? (`메뉴 수정`)
          : (``)
        }
      </PageTitle>
      <TextField
        id="menuName"
        label="메뉴 이름"
        type="search"
        className={classes.textField}
        margin="normal"
        variant="outlined"
        autoComplete="off"
        value={props.menuName}
        onChange={props.handleInputChange('menuName')}
      />
      <TextField
        id="menuPrice"
        label="가격"
        type="search"
        className={classes.textField}
        margin="normal"
        variant="outlined"
        autoComplete="off"
        value={props.menuPrice}
        onChange={props.handleInputChange('menuPrice')}
      />
      {
        (props.menuNameList.length > 0) && (
          <FormGroup>
          {
            props.menuNameList.map((item, index) => (
              <FormControlLabel
                key={index}
                control={
                  <Checkbox
                    checked={item.checked}
                    value={index}
                    onChange={props.handleMenuNameCheckbox(index)}
                  />
                }
                label={item.name}
              />
            ))
          }
          </FormGroup>
        )  
      }
      {
        (location.pathname === '/menu/edit/new')
        ? (
            <AddButtonSet
              onClickCreate={() => alert('create button!')}
              onClickCancel={() => history.push('/menu')}
            />
          )
        : (match.params.menuId)
          ? (
            <EditButtonSet
              onClickUpdate={() => alert('update button!')}
              onClickDelete={() => alert('delete button!')}
              onClickCancel={() => history.push('/menu')}
            />
          )
          : (<></>)
      }
    </Paper>
  )
}

export default withRouter(MenuEditContent)
```

Comment: Does your `handleMenuNameCheckbox ` function invokes when you update of your `checkbox`?

Comment: @octobus Yes, `handleMenuNameCheckbox` is set on `onChange` props for `<Checkbox />`, if you meant this.

Comment: Are there any warnings in the console such as changing from uncontrolled to controlled?

Comment: @RyanCogswell No, as I click any checkbox, nothing shows on the console, which means it works fine in the backend - I can see with `console.log` that the state of checkbox I clicked is certainly changed. I don't know why changed `checked` state does not get updated in the component.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could reproduce this in a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason why my checkbox did not work was because I re-used the previous state incorrectly.

```js
// redux/modules/menu.js
const updateMenuNameList = createAction(UPDATE_MENU_NAME_LIST, payload => ({ menuNameList: payload.menuNameList }))

export const checkMenuNameList = (index) => (dispatch, getState) => {
  const { menu: { menuNameList } } = getState()
  const previousStatus = menuNameList[index].checked
  menuNameList[index].checked = !previousStatus
  dispatch(onCheckMenuNameList({ updatedMenuNameList: menuNameList }))
}
```

In above example, I fetched previous state from `getState()`, and extract `menuNameList` from it. `menuNameList`'s structure looks like below:

```js
[
  {
    name: String,
    checked: Boolean
  }
]
```

Each checkbox uses this array to display `name` and determine whether it is checked or not. When I click any checkbox, handler will change the clicked checkbox's `checked` value.

The problem arise from here: I accidentally re-used objects from the previous `menuNameList`, and updated it only with certain `checked` value changed. This is not a correct approach, because even if an inside property is changed, Redux or React has no idea what have changed! **React and Redux figure out state changes with shallow comparison of object**. So, even if store changed, React does not render the view, and changes does not get applied to the view!

To avoid this problem, we should make a new object for `menuNameList`. Maybe it is recommended to use library like `Immutable.js`.

```js
// redux/modules/menu.js
export const checkMenuNameList = (idx) => (dispatch, getState) => {
  const { menu: { menuNameList } } = getState()

  // deep copy
  const newMenuNameList = menuNameList.map((item, index) => {
    if (index !== idx) {
      const newMenu = {
        name: item.name,
        checked: item.checked
      }
      return newMenu
    } else {
      const newMenu = {
        name: item.name,
        checked: !item.checked
      }
      return newMenu
    }
  })

  dispatch(onCheckMenuNameList({ updatedMenuNameList: newMenuNameList }))
}
```